# Hibernate result - getting multiple entities in order

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to get multiple entities. Here is the pseudocode to explain my problem.

```
    String qString ="select a.*, b.*, c.* from a_table a, b_table b, c_table c where a.x = b.x and b.y = c.y";

    SQLQuery sqlQ = session.createSQLQuery(qString);

    //adding entities
    sqlQ.addEntity("a", a_table.class);
    sqlQ.addEntity("b", b_table.class);
    sqlQ.addEntity("c", c_table.class);

    //then executing
    List l = sqlQ.list();
```

This gives me an Arraylist containing Object[]'s, my problem is a, b and c entities are not in the order I wanted. Remember my query, "select a.*, b.*, c.* .." but entities in the Object[] is c,a,b. When I try to get an entity,

```
    Object[] rowObj = ReturnData.get(0);
    a_table aObj = rowObj[0];
```

it throws an exception because it cannot cast c obj into an a obj. I tried to re-order the entities in my query (selecting c,b,a instead of a,b,c for example) but the result order never changes, the Object[] is always containing c,a then b entities.

Any suggestions? How Hibernate decides this order?

Comment: I don't think that there is a smooth way to change the order, but you can use `instanceof` to check if `rowObj[0]` is `a_table` or not and then assign them accordingly

Comment: Why are you using Hibernate if you are just going to do stuff jdbc-style?

Comment: You could create a view, and map an entity to it